# Pyspark create multiple rows for a record that include a time range

Tags: python, pyspark, timestamp

I have a dataframe looks like this.

```
A  Start  End
1  1578   1581
1  1789   1790
2  1800   1802
```

start and end are epoch. 
And I want to create multiple rows by every seconds, like this

```
A  time
1  1578
1  1579
1  1580
1  1581
1  1789
1  1790
2  1800
2  1801
2  1802
```

How to do it in pyspark? (Don't need to keep the order)

Thank you!

Comment: 0

You need to do a non equi join against a support dataframe having all the seconds.

Is the value of A in the second row 1? or is a typo?

Comment: @StefanoGallotti it is one. this is to show you that A may not be distinct in the dataset.

Answer (score 4):

The idea is to create a `list`, encompassing the entire time span by including the intermediate `seconds`. For eg; for `Start = 1578` and `End = 1581`, we create a list `[1578,1579,1580,1581]`. To create this list, we first create a `UDF`. Once this list is obtained, we [explode](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.explode) it to get the required `dataframe`.

```
# Creating the DataFrame
values = [(1,1578,1581),(1,1789,1790),(2,1800,1802)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(values,['A','Start','End'])
df.show()
+---+-----+----+
|  A|Start| End|
+---+-----+----+
|  1| 1578|1581|
|  1| 1789|1790|
|  2| 1800|1802|
+---+-----+----+

# Import requisite packages
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col, explode, array, struct
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StructType, StructField, IntegerType

#Creating UDFs below to create a list.
def make_list(start,end):
    return list(range(start,end+1))
make_list_udf = udf(make_list,ArrayType(IntegerType()))

#Creating Lists of seconds finally.
df = df.withColumn('my_list',make_list_udf(col('Start'),col('End'))).drop('Start','End')
df.show(truncate=False)
+---+------------------------+
|A  |my_list                 |
+---+------------------------+
|1  |[1578, 1579, 1580, 1581]|
|1  |[1789, 1790]            |
|2  |[1800, 1801, 1802]      |
+---+------------------------+

#Exploding the Lists
df = df.withColumn('time', explode('my_list')).drop('my_list')
df.show()
+---+----+
|  A|time|
+---+----+
|  1|1578|
|  1|1579|
|  1|1580|
|  1|1581|
|  1|1789|
|  1|1790|
|  2|1800|
|  2|1801|
|  2|1802|
+---+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data are in dataframe df and you have a support dataframe s_df with the seconds, you can do:

```
df.alias("a").join(s_df.alias("b"), (col("a.Start") >= col("b.time)) & (col("a. End") <= col("b.time)), "inner").select(col("a.A"), col("b.time")).
```

It may become a problem in case of overlapping of "A"s. In that case you may want to make "A" unique to establish with epoch belongs to which